# mySql rank sorting from-to

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting

I got a table like this:

`users`:

```
   | username |              statistics              |
   ----------- ---------------------------------------
0  | peter200 | { "gamesWon": 4, "gamesPlayed" : 4}  | 
1  | eminem33 | { "gamesWon": 7, "gamesPlayed" : 20} |
```

Note: *(statistics = "JSON")*

And I'd like to create a rank-list.

So the user with the highest number in `statistics. gamesWon` gets rank `numero uno 1` and so on.

What I've got so far is something like this (what is exactly working like I've hoped):

```
SELECT username, statistics, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank 
FROM users, (SELECT @rank := 0) r 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(statistics, '$.gamesWon') 
ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT(statistics, '$.gamesWon') DESC
```

---

**So to my question:** Now I'd like to update the query from above to just get the information in an specific rank-index *(lets say from rank 2 to rank 10)*.

Adding `AND rank > 2 AND rank < 10` to the `WHERE clause` does not seems to be a working solution. So any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can use your results into a Derived Table. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

Comment: I think I would do this in presentation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it with subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT username, statistics, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank 
      FROM users, (SELECT @rank := 0) r 
      WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(statistics, '$.gamesWon')
      ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT(statistics, '$.gamesWon') DESC
     ) s
WHERE  rank > 2 AND rank < 10
```

Comment: Obviously you are not Lukasz Szozda, you are `Usain Bolt`. Thanks. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the subquery.  You can use `limit` with `offset`:

```
SELECT username, statistics, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank 
FROM users CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) r 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(statistics, '$.gamesWon') 
ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT(statistics, '$.gamesWon') DESC
LIMIT 1, 9
```